# How to identify https clients through proxy connection

Tags: node.js, https, http-proxy, x-forwarded-for

We have developed a corporate NodeJS application served through http/2 protocol and we need to identify clients by their IP address because the server need to send events to clients based on their IP (basically some data about phone calls).

I can successfully get client IP through `req.connection.remoteAddress` but there are some of the clients that can only reach the server through our proxy server.

I know about `x-forwarded-for` header, but this doesn't work for us because proxies can't modify http headers in ssl connections.

So i though I could get the IP from client side and send back to the server, for example, during the login process.

But, if I'm not wrong, browsers doesn't provide that information to javascript so we need a way to obtain that information first.

Researching about it, the only option I found out is obtaining from a server which could tell me the IP from where I'm reaching it.

Of course, through https I can't because of the proxy. But I can easily enable an http service just to serve the client IP.

But then I found out that browsers blocks http connections from https-served pages because of "mixed active content" issue.

I read about it and I found out that I can get "[mixed passive content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content#Mixed_passivedisplay_content)" and I succeed in downloading garbage data as image file through `<img>`, but when I try to do the same thing using an `<object>` element I get a "mixed active content" block issue again even in MDN documentation it says it's considered *passive*.

Is there any way to read that data either by that (broken) `<img>` tag or am I missing something to make the `<object>` element really *passive*?

Any other idea to achieve our goal will also be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution:

As I said, I was able to perform an http request by putting an `<img>` tag.

What I was unable to do is to read downloaded data regardless if it were an actual image or not.

...but the fact is that the request was made and to which url is something that I can decide beforehand.

So all what I need to do is to generate a random key for each served login screen and:

- Remember it in association with your session data.
- Insert a, maybe hidden, `<img>` tag pointing to some http url containing that id.

As soon as your http server receive the request to download that image, you could read the real IP through the *x-forwarded-for* header (trusting your proxy, of course) and resolve to which active session it belongs.

Of course, you also must care to clear keys, regardless of being used or not, after a few time to avoid memory leak or even to be reused with malicious intentions.

**FINAL NOTE:** The only drawback of this approach is the risk that, some day, browsers could start blocking *mixed passive content* too by default.

For this reason I, in fact, opted by a double strategy approach. That is: additionally to the technique explained above, I also implemented an http redirector which does almost the same: It redirects all petitions to the root route ("/") to our https app. But it does so by a POST request containing a key which is previously associated to the client real IP.

This way, in case some day the first approach stops to work, users would be anyway able to access first through http. ...Which is in fact what we are going to do. But the first approach, while it continue working, could avoid problems if users decide to bookmark the page from within it (which will result in a bookmark to its https url).